# extract hashicorp vault secrets as values in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, hashicorp-vault, hashicorp

I am trying to extract specific value from kv2 hashicorp vault in ansible playbook using hashi_vault module

```yaml
- name: Return specific value from vault
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    secret: "{{ lookup('hashi_vault', 'secret=my.secrets/data/dev/heslo:value token=vault-plaintext-root-token url=http://10.47.0.235:8200/')}}"   register: secret
```

I am getting

```json
 {"msg": ""An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'hashi_vault'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: The secret my.secrets/data/dev/heslo doesn't seem to exist for hashi_vault lookup"}
```

Query works for all of the secrets in path using

```
secret=my.secrets/data/dev/
```

"heslo" record exists in the path

```json
      "ansible_facts": {
            "secret": {
                "data": {
                    "heslo": "heslo",
                    "password": "test",
                    "username": "ahoj"
                },
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for your `lookup` is for the KV1 engine. We can update it for the KV2 secrets engine:

```yaml
- name: Return specific value from vault
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    secret: "{{ lookup('hashi_vault', 'secret=my.secrets/data/dev token=vault-plaintext-root-token url=http://10.47.0.235:8200/') }}"
```

The `secret` fact will then be a dictionary containing all of the key value pairs at the specified secrets path `my.secrets/data/dev`. You can access the value of the key `heslo` with the normal syntax `secret['heslo']`.

Finally, you may also want to update to the [Vault collection for Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/hashi_vault/hashi_vault_lookup.html#ansible-collections-community-hashi-vault-hashi-vault-lookup) with all of its newer features.

Comment: There was a copy/paste error in OP's question (missing new line and bad indentation - I'm sure it's not a typo given the output) that you copy/pasted yourself and that was misleading. I fixed the question and your answer accordingly (i.e. there is no module called `secret`, no register is needed and yes, OP was already setting a fact).